# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cmd, pip

Facing error to install selenium library in python!
I am trying to do install selenium in python.

> python version python 3.11

> pip version 22.3

I tried to upgrade the pip library too

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and tried to install pip with following command

```
pip install -U selenium
```

or

```
pip.exe install selenium
```

I tried upgrade the pip library too

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and tried to install pip with following command

```
pip install -U selenium
```

or

```
pip.exe install selenium
```

Output:

```
yError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B388A79CD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/selenium/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001B388A7BED0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/selenium/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium
```

Comment: Errors seem to indicate an issue with a proxy server to fetch packages. Do you have one setup and is it configured properly/have the proper authentication?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Before run the command. I set proxy by set command. what type of setup or configured i need to setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run pip install command, open cmd and set your proxy

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy-host:proxy-port

set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy-host:proxy-port
```

Now run

```
pip install -U selenium
```